# Global Navigation not accessible in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, global-navigation

Global Navigation of Publishing Site is not accessible. When I access _api/navigation/MenuState?menuNodeKey=&mapProviderName=%27GlobalNavigationSwitchableProvider%27

I receive the following exception Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.REST.NavigationServiceException. I used the same user on another team site, there I received no error. Can't figure out what is the issue?

Answer (score -1):

This API should work fine in Publishing site.

You need to access the Publishing site to check if the global navigation is displayed correct.